# MYSQL- Finding the total amount of playtime (from a column) from all lines and getting a sum

Tags: mysql, sum

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i5y1aggfjzl39c/photo.png

I want to get a total amount of playtime from the 38,000 users.

In addition, I want the sql query that will add the previous amount on the "playtime" column from each line and find a final sum.

Edit: Im really unsure If I was specific enough, I never ever got in a hard situation like this at expressing myself with English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT SUM(Playtime) FROM players;

That will give you the total amount of playtime from all users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the accumulated time on each row, try something like

```
SELECT   @accumulated:=@accumulated+playtime as accum FROM players, (select @accumulated:=0) as accum
```